# Windows start command on shortcut gives error "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a small Windows batch script to launch some shortcuts using the `start` command.

One of the shortcuts always fails with an message box: `"The parameter is incorrect"`.  I can use command `dir` to see the file.  (I can also double click the shortcut from Windows Explorer and it works OK.)

What I am doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\arpeke>dir "\\UBSPROD.MSAD.UBS.NET\UserData\ARPEKE\RF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start\JetBrains TeamCity Tray Notifier.lnk"
 Volume in drive \\UBSPROD.MSAD.UBS.NET\UserData is NHKG3850PAU_E
 Volume Serial Number is 5C9C-845E

 Directory of \\UBSPROD.MSAD.UBS.NET\UserData\ARPEKE\RF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start

2015-02-20  11:39 AM             2,465 JetBrains TeamCity Tray Notifier.lnk
               1 File(s)          2,465 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  45,806,698,496 bytes free

C:\Users\arpeke>start "" "\\UBSPROD.MSAD.UBS.NET\UserData\ARPEKE\RF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\start\JetBrains TeamCity Tray Notifier.lnk"
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Is user allowed to access that file/folder in that network drive?

Comment: @Biswa: Sorry, is it unclear above?  I can `dir` the file.  Is that not enough?  Also, I mentioned I can run the shortcut from Windows Explorer.

Comment: `start shell:startup\$name.ink` give the same error?

Comment: Why not use just execute the lnk path without using start command?

Comment: @Biswa: Same error.